# Pandas XlsxWriter export to new folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hey guys is there way at the .writer stage to export files into a new separate folder named say "Report Cards'

I've tried to search and can't seem to find anything.

Here is my code at the end for writing the .xlsx:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Part_Report_Card_' + fname, engine='xlsxwriter')
header.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report Card', index=False, header=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report Card', startrow=7, startcol=0, 
index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create the folder first, the writer doesn't seem able to do it.
Try with this method :

```
import os
report_path = 'Report Cards'
if not os.path.exists(report_path):
    os.makedirs(report_path)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(report_path, 
                        'Part_Report_Card_' + fname), 
                        engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: @SamRussoPalmer, thanks for telling me, i was too confident with the first try...